# View controller crash fixed by renaming class

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xib

Had a UIViewController subclass with a XIB that has a table view, which I decided to turn into a UITableViewController subclass without XIB.

So in the .`h`eader I changed:

```
@interface AViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,
                                               UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView* tableView;
```

to:

```
@interface AViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>
```

And in the `.m`odule file changed a line in my `init` from:

```
if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"AView" bundle:nil])
```

to:

```
if (self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain])
```

That should be all you'd expect.  But when I run the app it crashes.  The `init` is called and return, but soon after that a crash.  `viewDidLoad` etc. are not called.

Things I've tried many things: Remove the XIB, Clean Build Folder..., removed app from device, restarted Xcode, restarted Mac, but nothing worked.

What did work was renaming `AViewController` to `AViewController_` in this module and then where it was used in my app.

My guess is that there's some memory of XIB and that the XIB is still being instantiated; but it's a weird guess.

Any idea what this could be and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have any crash logs?

Comment: @rounak I have All Exception breakpoint, but it went straight to `main()`; something you typically see when there something wrong with a XIB.  As a last resort I'm now downloading the latest Xcode 5 and iOS 7 beta; so I can't give details at the moment.

Comment: Since you changed it from UIViewController to UITableViewController, the view property is expected to be be a tableview. Maybe the xib is giving it a normal UIView? I'm guessing when you changed the class name, the nib no longer is associated with your class and hence it doesn't crash.

Comment: @rounak But there's no XIB anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated all my other XIBs to Xcode 5 and the problem disappeared.